# Repeat rows in files in wakari

Tags: python

In wakari, how do I download a CSV file and create a new CSV file with each of the rows in the original file repeated N number of times in the new CSV file.

Comment: Do you want the entire file repeated N times (1,2,3 => 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), or do you want the lines individually repeated (1,2,3 => 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)?

Comment: Also, what work do you have so far, so that we may build upon it?

Comment: import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/ish-history.csv")... I want to add some more data by repeating the rows.

Comment: The duplication is flexible.. 1,2,3,1,2,3.. is fine. The whole intention is to make a dataset where the MS Excel will fail to open it. If you have any dataset which cannot be opened by MS Excel, please forward if its not confidential. I am working on Python with wakari.

Answer (score 0):

`cat dataset.csv dataset.csv dataset.csv dataset.csv > bigdata.csv`